# Create File command failed while creating DF in SmartCrad

Tags: smartcard, apdu, gemalto

I am trying to create New Dedicated file(DF) using create file command with following data field:

`62 1A 81 02 04 00 82 01 38 83 02 3F 20 8A 01 05 8C 04 43 12 11 11 9C 04 43 12 11 11`

I am getting following Error : **69 85** (Condition of use not satisfied)

I am using Gemalto IDPrime 830 SmartCard and following ISO 7816-4 (2005) standard.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemalto IDPrime is a javacard as opposed to a native (file-system based) card. Therefore you won't be able to create DF if no applet is present supporting this command. (While theoretically possible, it is not likely, since javacards use a different paradigm.)

Update with your newly added information: 6985 means it is **not** a permission problem, and also does **not** related to wrong parameters of the command data field. Note, that some cards have a limit on the nesting level of DFs, so the MF is most sure choice to create a DF.

Comment: using the above command i successfully created EF files in  Gemalto IDPrime smart card, following the same procedure, i am unable to create DF.  According to the policy of mentioned card we can create EF and DF both.